# Find files based on modified date(specifying the exact hour)

Tags: bash, find

My question is:

How to find files that has been modified from a given date(specifying the exact hour) to another given date(specifying the exact hour) in a given directory, from / for example.

I think that can be achieved with `find`.

Does anyone know how to do this¿? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 46, accepted):

go for this one:

`find . -newermt "2013-01-01 00:00:00" ! -newermt "2013-01-02 00:00:00"`

m   The modification time of the file reference

t   reference is interpreted directly as a time

Comment: Nice shot. Allowed me to get which application created that big '~/.m2' dir by looking in /usr/bin based on the date and time! It's guacamole/freerdp.

Comment: Instead of `!`, you may use `-not` to increase readability and compatibility with all shell types (bash, zsh, etc.).

Comment: Using ```-not``` instead of ```!``` may avoid problems with some shells, but it isn’t POSIX-compliant, so it won’t work on all versions of Unix.

Answer (score 5):

The basic structure of the `find` command looks like this:

```
# find <paths> <filters> <actions>

find / -mtime -10 -mtime +4
```

`find` has `+` and `-` operators that work with the `mtime`, `atime` and `ctime` options:

```
atime == Access Time
mtime == Modified Time
ctime == Change Time
```

You can read `inode` with `-*time` and define intervals for your times via `+` and/or `-`

Comment: (1) Specifying modification time limits to the granularity of an exact hour seems to be a major focus of this question.   This answer doesn’t even mention that.   (2) This answer copies most of an earlier answer, and adds very little explanation.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do it with below:

```
find ./* -mtime -10 -mtime +4 -ls
```

Comment: For based on hrs and min
You need to find the numbers mins -- from and to, to be used in below:

find ./* -mmin -540 -mmin +20 -ls

Comment: You can edit your onw posts to improve them with relevant information. Keep the comments for more non-essential stuff.